# Reverse place id using PlacesService

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am looking for a way to avoid being charged for

- Places API Atmosphere Data
- Places API Contact Data

I only need to reverse the place id to its [formatted_address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult). Any idea about what changes I need to do in the code bellow?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865381/google-maps-autocomplete-without-atmosphere-data), although I am not using `Autocomplete` but `PlacesService`.

---

```
$('.company_location_id').each(function(i, obj) {
    if ($(this).length > 0) {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            var request = {
                placeId: $(this).val()
            };

            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementsByClassName($(this).attr('class'))[0]);
            service.getDetails(request, callback);

            var new_text = $(this)

            function callback(place, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    $(new_text).next().text(place.formatted_address);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid charges for Atmosphere Data and Contact Data using the `PlacesService`, you should specify a list of fields to be retrieved in the `PlaceDetailsRequest` object that you pass as a first parameter in `getDetails()` function.

Have a look at the documentation of `PlaceDetailsRequest` interface:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceDetailsRequest

As you can see this interface has `fields` property

> **fields** - Fields to be included in the details response. For a list of fields see PlaceResult. Nested fields can be specified with dot-paths (for example, "geometry.location").

So, you should define request in your code as

```
var request = {
    placeId: $(this).val(),
    fields: ["formatted_address"]
};
```

I hope this helps!