# Google Maps Autocomplete WITHOUT Atmosphere Data reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api, search-box

I'm facing a similar problem like this post [Google Maps Autocomplete WITHOUT Atmosphere Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865381/google-maps-autocomplete-without-atmosphere-data) but I'm just looking for a solution that could be applied in reactjs.

I'm already using this wrapper
https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps

But I cannot find where to put the AutocompleteOptions.

Comment: This library hasn't exposed the Autocomplete Feature. You have 3 options :
1. use a different library/direct JS. 2. Ask this library owner to add that feature/expose api. 3 you write it yourself and submit PR

Answer (score 1):

The [react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/) library does not include the Place Autocomplete service; it only offers [SearchBox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox) which doesn't allow you to specify fields. However I've done a quick search and have found the following reactjs libraries (and I'm sure there are a few more out there):

1. [react-google-autocomplete](https://github.com/ErrorPro/react-google-autocomplete) which states the following in its readme:

   > You can also set fields prop if you need extra information, now it
   >   defaults to basic data in order to control expenses.
2. [react-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete) which doesn't currently support fields as per [this issue](https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete/issues/271).
3. [react-google-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/Tintef/react-google-places-autocomplete) which based on the documentation doesn't appear to support specifying fields either.

Note that you can always file a FR or submit a PR yourself.

My approach: take a look at [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-surf-pq6t0) to see an Autocomplete input in action using #1 that only requests Basic Data fields. Add your own API key to the Google Maps JS API script in index.html to run it.

Hope this helps!