# How to disable Atmosphere Data on Google AutocompleteService

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Others have asked [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865381/google-maps-autocomplete-without-atmosphere-data)

However the difference is that they were using `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` which is the widget that builds an auto complete UI for you. As others have answered in the other questions, this widget has a method called `setFields` which you can specify which fields you want (so you can stop getting atmospheric data and stop getting charged for it)

However I am using the [google.maps.places.AutocompleteService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service) so I can build my own auto complete UI without using their widget.

However this service does not have a `setFields` method or any other way that I am aware of to specify the fields to stop getting charged for atmospheric data.

Is there a way to turn off atmosphere data with this?

Comment: The Autocomplete Service class does not return any place information and that includes atmosphere data. You get these by doing a Place Details request. Use session tokens so you don't get charged for Autocomplete requests if you use Places Details. See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I have it figured out,

When you get the place ID from the auto complete service and then fetch more details, that is where you can specify the fields:

```js
const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'))
service.getDetails({
  placeId: id,
  fields: ['address_components', 'geometry', 'name']
}, callback)
```